# Deriving Newton's second law of motion for charged particles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics

I am trying to derive Newton's second law of motion for two charged particles with opposing charges and the same mass using Coulomb's law.

Let $q_{(+)}$ and $q_{(-)}$ be positively and negatively charged particles separated in air by a distance $\left|\vec{r}\right|$. Then the Coulomb force would be $$\vec{F} = \frac{q_{(+)}q_{(-)}}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}\left|\vec{r}\right|^{2}}\hat{r}$$

Now, Newton's second law, $$\vec{F} = m\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}t^{2}}\vec{x} = m\vec{a}$$It can be equated to the Coulomb's force, giving $$\vec{F} = \frac{q_{(+)}q_{(-)}}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}\left|\vec{r}\right|^{2}}\hat{r} = m_{(+)}\vec{a_{(+)}} + m_{(-)}\vec{a_{(-)}}$$ $$\Rightarrow \vec{a_{(+)}} + \vec{a_{(-)}} = \frac{q_{(+)}q_{(-)}}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}M\left|\vec{r}\right|^{2}}\hat{r} = \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}t^{2}}\vec{x_{(+)}} + \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}t^{2}}\vec{x_{(-)}}$$

$$\boxed{\therefore\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}t^{2}}\vec{x_{(+)}} + \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}t^{2}}\vec{x_{(-)}} = \frac{q_{(+)}q_{(-)}}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}M\left|\vec{r}\right|^{2}}\hat{r}}$$

where $m_{(+)} = m_{(-)} = M$.

So please I'd like to know if this equation represents what I am trying to derive? If it does, is there an easier way to write this equation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $m_{(+)}$ and $m_{(-)}$ are the masses of the positive and negative charge, then they certainly are not equal.

Comment: The equation after "I can be equated to the Coulomb's force, giving" is not correct. That is the force on one of the two charges, not the total force on both of them. If $\vec{r}$ is defined as $\vec{r}_+-\vec{r}_-$ (a vector pointing from negative to positive - you never said which way it points), it's the force acting on the positive charge, and an equal and opposite force acts on the negative charge. If two objects exert a force on one another, and there are no external forces, the total force on both objects is always zero (one of newton's laws essentially). So $m_+a_++m_-a_-=0$ always.

Comment: Look up "dynamics of systems of particles". This is a standard problem in mechanics textbooks.

Comment: @BobD In the problem, it was given that the mass of the two particles are equal.

Comment: @AXensen, if I understand you correctly, you're saying that the forces of $q_{(+)}$ and $q_{(-)}$ add up to $0$?

Comment: @nasu, could you please link me a reference? I tried searching but couldn't get a page or article about this.

Comment: How far along are you in electromagnetism? That formula for force is incomplete in the general case. Starting from rest, the Coulomb force causes an acceleration, but accelerating charges emit radiation resulting a force in addition to the Coulomb force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force $\vec F$ in your first equation is either the force exerted on $m_{(-)}$ due to $m_{(+)}$ or the force exerted on $m_{(+)}$ due to $m_{(-)}$. For the former the equation should be written as

$$\vec F_{m(-)}=\frac{q_{(+)}q_{(-)}}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}r^{2}}\hat r_{+,-}$$

where $\hat r_{+,-}$ is a unit vector directed from the positively charged particle to the negatively charged particle.

For the latter it should be written as

$$\vec F_{m(+)}=\frac{q_{(+)}q_{(-)}}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}r^{2}}\hat r_{-,+}$$

where $\hat r_{-,+}$ is now a unit vector directed from the negatively charged particle to the positively charged particle.

In any case, from Newton's 3rd law applies, that is

$$\vec F_{m(-)}=-\vec F_{m(+)}$$

So with regards to your third equation, $\vec F$ would be the net force acting on the two particle system and will always be zero, unless another external (to the system) force happens to be acting on the system.

Finally, the acceleration of each particle is determined by applying Newton's 2nd law to each individually. If the two charged particles have equal mass, then of course the magnitudes of their accelerations will be equal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it did help. My attempt is to try and form a differential equation so I would be able to solve this numerically. Now I see that it's not one differential equation, but a system of two differential equations. Hope I am right?

Comment: yes you are. You need to apply Newton's 2nd law twice except for the trivial case where the magnitudes of the charges and the masses are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Second Law:

$m_+\frac{d^2 x_{q_+}}{dt^2}=\frac{q_+q_- }{4\pi \epsilon_0r}$

$m_-\frac{d^2 x_{q_-}}{dt^2}=\frac{-q_+q_- }{4\pi \epsilon_0r}$

$r=|\vec{x_+}-\vec{x_-}|$

The total force is $\vec{0}$ and not what you have circled.

Note this is consistent with the Third Law:

$m_+\vec{a_+}+m_-\vec{a_-}=0$

This implies $m_+ \vec{v_+}+ m_-\vec{v_-}=\vec{c_1}$, i.e. momentum is constant.

Integrate again with respect to time

$m_+\ \vec{x_+}+m_-\vec{x_-}=\vec{c_1}t+\vec{c_2}$, i.e. the center of mass is moving at constant velocity.

If you take $\vec{c_1}=\vec{0}$, you get the remaining terms in the center of momentum frame.  That allows you to transform this from one two-body problem to two one-body problems.

$\vec{x_-} = (\vec{c_2}-m_+)/m_-$

Comment: Thank you, I realized that I had to split the two forces into a system of equations.